Renovate update image version and digest in the same PR
I have renovate setup with the config bellow. This results in two PRs (the digest update only happens after the version is merged).
Do you see any issue with my config?
My main objective here is to update the version but also to have se security of digest pinning.
If I add "docker:pinDigests", the version updates stop working
Thank you
Image declaration example (k8s):
image: ghcr.io/stirling-tools/s-pdf:0.25.1@sha256:c510d267ad6c2d4062f0b6ead3ce4201a888a07ba1c685359d4ba09a4c48cb26


{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "labels": ["dependencies", "renovate"],
  "ignorePaths": [
    "Kubernetes/secrets_raw"
  ],
  "minimumReleaseAge": "7 days",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended",
    "config:base"
  ],
  "helm-values": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "\\.ya?ml$"
    ]
  },
  "kubernetes": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "\\.ya?ml$" 
    ]
  },
  "argocd": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "\\.ya?ml$"
    ]
  },"docker": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "Dockerfile",
      ".*\\.dockerfile$",
      "Dockerfile.*",
      "\\.ya?ml$"
    ]
  },
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      "description": "Process custom dependencies",
      "fileMatch": [
        "\\.ya?ml$"
      ],
      "matchStrings": [
        "datasource=(?<datasource>\\S+) depName=(?<depName>\\S+)( versioning=(?<versioning>\\S+))?\n.*?\"(?<currentValue>.*)\"\n"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "{{#if datasource}}{{{datasource}}}{{else}}github-releases{{/if}}",
      "versioningTemplate": "{{#if versioning}}{{{versioning}}}{{else}}semver{{/if}}"
    },
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "\\.ya?ml$"
      ],
      "matchStrings": [
        "image: (?<depName>[^:\\s]+):(?<currentValue>[^@\\s]+)@sha256:(?<digest>[a-fA-F0-9]+)"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "docker",
      "versioningTemplate": "docker"
    }
  ]
}




For my use case of updating Docker Compose files, I used the groupName setting to get merged PRs of the version number and digest updates. I hope it helps to adjust your config.
{
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "description": "Config to group Docker image version and digest updates into a single pull request.",
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["docker"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["digest", "major", "minor", "patch"],
      "groupName": "{{depName}} Docker updates"
    }
  ]
}

